# Turn on labels for an ArcGIS dynamic MapServer layer

Tags: labeling, arcgis-rest-api, dynamic-layer

While I am generally knowledgeable about using the ArcGIS Server REST API to work with dynamic MapServer layers, this is the first time I have tried to turn on labels.

Below is a call for a tile that will display a single green circle.
The value of POITYPE is Visitor Center.
I would like the label ‘Visitor Center’ to appear near the green circle.

Alas, I have been unable to conjure up just the right syntax to make that happen.
What am I missing?

[https://mapservices.nps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NationalDatasets/NPS_Public_POIs/MapServer/export?bbox=-12205302.24789184,4667760.897033789,-12200410.278081588,4665802.198183983&size=1024,410&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&dynamicLayers=[{'source':{'type':'mapLayer','mapLayerId':0},'definitionExpression':"upper(POITYPE)='VISITOR+CENTER'",'drawingInfo':{'renderer':{'type':'simple','symbol':{'type':'esriSMS','style':'esriSMSCircle','color':[0,255,0,255],'size':8,'outline':{'color':[0,0,0,255],'width':1.5}}}},'showLabels':true,'labelingInfo':{'labelPlacement':'esriServerPointLabelPlacementAboveRight','labelExpression':[POITYPE],'useCodedValues':false,'symbol':{color:[0,255,255,255],'size':8,'fontFamily':'Arial','fontStyle':'normal','fontWeight':'bold','fontDecoration':'none'}}}]&layers=show:0&f=image](https://mapservices.nps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NationalDatasets/NPS_Public_POIs/MapServer/export?bbox=-12205302.24789184,4667760.897033789,-12200410.278081588,4665802.198183983&size=1024,410&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&dynamicLayers=[%7B'source':%7B'type':'mapLayer','mapLayerId':0%7D,'definitionExpression':%22upper(POITYPE)='VISITOR%20CENTER'%22,'drawingInfo':%7B'renderer':%7B'type':'simple','symbol':%7B'type':'esriSMS','style':'esriSMSCircle','color':[0,255,0,255],'size':8,'outline':%7B'color':[0,0,0,255],'width':1.5%7D%7D%7D%7D,'showLabels':true,'labelingInfo':%7B'labelPlacement':'esriServerPointLabelPlacementAboveRight','labelExpression':[POITYPE],'useCodedValues':false,'symbol':%7Bcolor:[0,255,255,255],'size':8,'fontFamily':'Arial','fontStyle':'normal','fontWeight':'bold','fontDecoration':'none'%7D%7D%7D]&layers=show:0&f=image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your dynamicLayers definition.

- It's not valid JSON:

  - JSON uses double quotes, not single (use single quotes in `upper(POITYPE)='VISITOR CENTER'`)
  - Missing quotes for `labelExpression`
  - Missing quotes for `color`
- `showLabels` and `labelingInfo` should be inside `drawingInfo`
- `font` should be a separate JSON object, i.e. `"font": { "name": "Arial", etc }`

See here for details: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/export-map.htm#

Here's a sample that should get you going:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "NPS_Public_POIs",
        "source": {
            "type": "mapLayer",
            "mapLayerId": 0
        },
        "definitionExpression": "upper(POITYPE)='VISITOR CENTER'",
        "drawingInfo": {
            "renderer": {
                "type": "simple",
                "symbol": {
                    "color": [
                        0,
                        255,
                        0,
                        255
                    ],
                    "size": 8,
                    "type": "esriSMS",
                    "style": "esriSMSCircle",
                    "outline": {
                        "color": [
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            255
                        ],
                        "width": 1.5,
                        "type": "esriSLS",
                        "style": "esriSLSSolid",
                        "marker": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "showLabels": true,
            "labelingInfo": [
                {
                    "labelExpression": "[POITYPE]",
                    "useCodedValues": false,
                    "maxScale": 0,
                    "minScale": 0,
                    "where": null,
                    "labelPlacement": "esriServerPointLabelPlacementAboveCenter",
                    "symbol": {
                        "color": [
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            255
                        ],
                        "type": "esriTS",                        
                        "horizontalAlignment": "left",
                        "font": {
                            "size": 8,
                            "style": "normal",
                            "variant": "normal",
                            "decoration": "normal",
                            "weight": "normal",
                            "family": "Arial"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "minScale": 0,
        "maxScale": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

@Berend - Thanks for taking the time to help!  I marked your post as the answer. I was also missing some square brackets and "type":"esriTS" appears to be required.

I am posting an 'answer' instead of a 'comment' so I can include the finished tile call in case it helps someone else up the learning curve.

Here is the finished tile call.

[https://mapservices.nps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NationalDatasets/NPS_Public_POIs/MapServer/export?bbox=-12205302.24789184,4667760.897033789,-12200410.278081588,4665802.198183983&size=1024,410&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&dynamicLayers=[{"source":{"type":"mapLayer","mapLayerId":0},"definitionExpression":"upper(POITYPE)='VISITOR+CENTER'","drawingInfo":{"renderer":{"type":"simple","symbol":{"type":"esriSMS","style":"esriSMSCircle","color":[0,255,0,255],"size":8,"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":1.5}}},"showLabels":true,"labelingInfo":[{"labelPlacement":"esriServerPointLabelPlacementAboveRight","labelExpression":"[POITYPE]","useCodedValues":false,"symbol":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"type":"esriTS","font":{"size":14,"fontFamily":"Arial","fontStyle":"normal","fontWeight":"bold","fontDecoration":"none"}}}]}}]&layers=show:0&f=image](https://mapservices.nps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NationalDatasets/NPS_Public_POIs/MapServer/export?bbox=-12205302.24789184,4667760.897033789,-12200410.278081588,4665802.198183983&size=1024,410&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&dynamicLayers=[%7B%22source%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mapLayer%22,%22mapLayerId%22:0%7D,%22definitionExpression%22:%22upper(POITYPE)='VISITOR%20CENTER'%22,%22drawingInfo%22:%7B%22renderer%22:%7B%22type%22:%22simple%22,%22symbol%22:%7B%22type%22:%22esriSMS%22,%22style%22:%22esriSMSCircle%22,%22color%22:[0,255,0,255],%22size%22:8,%22outline%22:%7B%22color%22:[0,0,0,255],%22width%22:1.5%7D%7D%7D,%22showLabels%22:true,%22labelingInfo%22:[%7B%22labelPlacement%22:%22esriServerPointLabelPlacementAboveRight%22,%22labelExpression%22:%22[POITYPE]%22,%22useCodedValues%22:false,%22symbol%22:%7B%22color%22:[0,0,0,255],%22type%22:%22esriTS%22,%22font%22:%7B%22size%22:14,%22fontFamily%22:%22Arial%22,%22fontStyle%22:%22normal%22,%22fontWeight%22:%22bold%22,%22fontDecoration%22:%22none%22%7D%7D%7D]%7D%7D]&layers=show:0&f=image)